# Removing parenthesis from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have a list

```
{(Row[{Subscript[x, 2]}]\[CirclePlus]1)/Subscript[x, 1],
 (Row[{Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 3]}]\[CirclePlus]1)/Subscript[x, 2], 
 (Row[{Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 4]}]\[CirclePlus]1)/Subscript[x, 3], 
 (Row[{Subscript[x, 3]}]\[CirclePlus]1)/Subscript[x, 4], 
 (Row[{Subscript[y, 2]}]\[CirclePlus]1)/Subscript[x, 1], 
 (Subscript[x, 1]\[CirclePlus]Subscript[y, 3])/Subscript[x, 2], 
 (Subscript[x, 2]\[CirclePlus]Subscript[y, 4])/Subscript[x, 3],
 (Subscript[y, 3]\[CirclePlus](Subscript[y, 2] + Subscript[y, 3]))/Subscript[x, 1], 
 (Row[{Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[y, 4]}]\[CirclePlus]
    Row[{Subscript[y, 3] + Subscript[y, 4]}])/Subscript[x, 2], 
 ((Subscript[y, 3] + Subscript[y,4])\[CirclePlus]
    (Subscript[y, 2] + Subscript[y, 3] + Subscript[y, 4]))/Subscript[x, 1]}
```

which looks like this in standard form.

[image: std_form]

From that list I want to remove all the `( )` parenthesis, wherever they appear. I thought that the most natural approach would be to use ReplaceAll, for instance, something along this line:

```
list /. (___) -> ___
```

But this doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: i think you can use Flatten

Comment: I believe that I've tried this already, on different levels, but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer but an attempt to get the OP to clarify his/her thinking and then to rephrase the question to express what is really in question.

---

You can't replace parentheses in expressions. Internally they don't exist and will never be matched. Parentheses only show up in Notebooks and scripts where binary operator symbols are used as a user input convenience. Formally, the Wolfram Language is parentheses-free. Operators are not binary but take the form `OpHead[___]`, which allows any number of arguments.

You should study your expression as it is output by `FullForm` and see what the pattern matcher sees.

```
<your expression> // FullForm
```

which will give

[image: fullform]

As you can see from the above, there is not one set of parentheses to match.

Comment: Thank you @m_goldberg ! That is actually a very useful answer, very useful thing to know. To give you some more background, the issue that I'm facing with the list above is that when I'm replacing expression involving y (using ReplaceAll), say Plus[Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[y, 3], Subscript[y, 4]], it replaces Plus[Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[y, 3]] and  Subscript[y, 3] separately, in some cases, in others it doesn't, which seems really odd and I'm struggling to see why this is happening...Can you think of any possible issues?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want the formatting of [`CirclePlus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePlus) to have a lower precedence than [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus). One idea would be to modify the formatting of [`CirclePlus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePlus) to do this:

```
MakeBoxes[CirclePlus[a__], form_] := RowBox @ Riffle[
    Thread[Unevaluated[Parenthesize[{a}, form, 300, None]]],
    "\[CirclePlus]"
]
```

Then your example looks like:

```
{
(Row[{Subscript[x,2]}]⊕1)/Subscript[x,1],
(Row[{Subscript[x,1],Subscript[x,3]}]⊕1)/Subscript[x,2],
(Row[{Subscript[x,2],Subscript[x,4]}]⊕1)/Subscript[x,3],
(Row[{Subscript[x,3]}]⊕1)/Subscript[x,4],
(Row[{Subscript[y,2]}]⊕1)/Subscript[x,1],
(Subscript[x,1]⊕Subscript[y,3])/Subscript[x,2],
(Subscript[x,2]⊕Subscript[y,4])/Subscript[x,3],
(Subscript[y,3]⊕(Subscript[y,2]+Subscript[y,3]))/Subscript[x,1],
(Row[{Subscript[x,1],Subscript[y,4]}]⊕Row[{Subscript[y,3]+Subscript[y,4]}])/Subscript[x,2],
((Subscript[y,3]+Subscript[y,4])⊕(Subscript[y,2]+Subscript[y,3]+Subscript[y,4]))/Subscript[x,1]
} //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\frac{x_2\oplus 1}{x_1},\frac{x_1x_3\oplus 1}{x_2},\frac{x_2x_4\oplus 1}{x_3},\frac{x_3\oplus
>    1}{x_4},\frac{y_2\oplus 1}{x_1},\frac{x_1\oplus y_3}{x_2},\frac{x_2\oplus y_4}{x_3},\frac{y_3\oplus
>    y_2+y_3}{x_1},\frac{x_1y_4\oplus y_3+y_4}{x_2},\frac{y_3+y_4\oplus y_2+y_3+y_4}{x_1}\right\}$